# Forward custom header apache

Tags: apache

Is it possible to forward custom http header when using redirect or rewrite on apache?

My use case is:

- I am receiving a request from *some.domain.com* with custom http header *custom-param*.
- I need to resend the request to *another.domain.com* and I need the custom header to be preserved.

How can I achieve this in Apache 2.2?

Comment: I am no expert but I would look into the [mod_headers module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with an arbitrary header, it would only be possible if you could settle for a cookie set against *.domain.com.  Only a cookie would be re-sent after the redirect.

Comment: Is it not possible to some how rewrite the header from old request into the new one?